# .symlink lost its target once reboot the pc

Tags: apache, cmd, xampp, certbot, mklink

I have one website virtual hosting under xampp apache and using certbot to obtain ssl cert

```
certbot certonly --webroot --w C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mysite\\wordpress --d www.mysite.com
```

**After successful obtain**
It created 4 pem files in C:\Certbox\archive\mysite\ and 4 .smylink(.pem) files in C:\Certbox\live\mysite\ which symlink to those 4 files on archive folder

**Heres the problem:**
Everytime I reboot the pc, those 4 .smylink(.pem) files seems lost its target to those 4 pem files in C:\Certbox\archive\mysite\ and seems to became broken and preventing xampp apache from starting

**What I've tried:**

1. Cmd run `cd C:\Certbot\live\mysite\` then `del cert.pem.symlink` and recreate `mklink /H cert.pem.symlink C:\Certbot\archive\mysite\cert.pem`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue you're facing is related to symbolic links being broken after a system reboot. Windows might reset the symbolic links or the paths might change during startup.

One solution is to create a batch script that recreates the symbolic links each time your computer starts up. Here's an example of how you can create a simple batch script:

1. Open Notepad or any text editor.
2. Copy and paste the following script into the editor:

   > ```
   > @echo off
   >
   > set certbot_path=C:\Certbot
   > set site_name=mysite
   >
   > mklink /H "%certbot_path%\live\%site_name%\cert.pem.symlink" "%certbot_path%\archive\%site_name%\cert.pem"
   > mklink /H "%certbot_path%\live\%site_name%\privkey.pem.symlink" "%certbot_path%\archive\%site_name%\privkey.pem"
   > mklink /H "%certbot_path%\live\%site_name%\fullchain.pem.symlink" "%certbot_path%\archive\%site_name%\fullchain.pem"
   > mklink /H "%certbot_path%\live\%site_name%\chain.pem.symlink" "%certbot_path%\archive\%site_name%\chain.pem"
   >
   > exit
   > ```
3. Save the file with a .bat extension, for example, recreate_links.bat. Save it to a location of your choice.

To make this script run on startup, you can create a shortcut to it and place the shortcut in the Startup folder.

4. Press `Win + R` to open the Run dialog.
5. Type `shell:startup` and press Enter. This opens the Startup folder.
6. Copy the shortcut of your `recreate_links.bat` script into this folder.

Now, every time your computer starts up, it will execute the batch script and recreate the symbolic links for you.

PS: Adjust the paths in the script if your actual paths are different.

PPS: This has never happened to me as I primarily use a Linux-based System.

Comment: Btw check & Verify that XAMPP services are set to start after the Certbot service. You can adjust the startup order in the Windows Services configuration.
XAMPP Configuration Issue:

Double-check your XAMPP Apache configuration files (httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf, etc.) to ensure that the paths to SSL certificate files are correctly set.

Ideally this should be checked first.

Comment: How do i check & Verify that XAMPP services are set to start after the Certbot service